# Regex for fixed length string, starting with number

Tags: regex, validation

I am using Bootstrap validator and try to validate a fixed length string with regex. The string is fixed length of exactly 7 alphanumeric characters. The format is "AAABBCC", which AAA is three digit number range from 201-232, and BB are 2 characters only accept NE,NF,SE,SF,SW, and then CC is two digit number range from 04-16 with leading 0. For example, the followings are both matched:

232SE14
223SW01
222SE06

Please let me know how to write this in regex.

Comment: `223SW01` does not match your stated requirements, because `01` is not in the range *from 04-16*.

Answer (score -1):

Try following regex

```
/^(20[1-9]|2[12][0-9]|23[0-2])(NE|NF|SE|SF|SW)(?:0[4-9]|1[0-6])$/
```

By the way, second string doesn’t match because 01 is outside of 04~16.

Comment: If you wish to recognize a suggestion in a comment it's best to leave a comment, rather than doing so in the answer, to keep the latter clean. Moreover, there's no need to mention in the answer that you've edited it. Sometimes you'll find that the person who made the comment deletes it after seeing you've incorporated it into your answer. It's because the want to keep the focus on the answer and consider attention to their comment a distraction. There's no point asking a downvoter to step forward. It won't happen. We all get downvotes for reasons unknown. Just move on.

Comment: The answer was edited per @cary-awoveland suggestion.